# Rails - How to update a record , then dynamically update values on another model based on the value of the record being modified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue**

Say I have a scaffold named `ServiceMenu` that only contains only one drop down menu which has 3 values of *Brakes*, *Pads*, and *Muffler*.
I have `Service` model which stores all the services that belongs to user's on a model called, `Tech`. Each `tech` has the ability of adding a any one of the `service_menu` (*Brakes*, *Pads*, and *Muffler*) to their db profile which is called, `services`.

The problem I forsee is if I were update any one of the `ServiceMenu` names say from *Brakse* to *Brakes*, the `techs` will still have the old `service_menu` name in their profile. I would find myself doing a lot of housekeeping updating well over 1000 records due to a *typo* or simply wanting to update the `ServiceMenu` name.

---

**Files**

**service_menu.rb**

```
class ServiceMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end
```

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tech
  belongs_to :service_menu
end
```

---

**service_menus_controller.rb**

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
  if @service_menu.update(service_menu_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @service_menu, notice: 'Service menu was successfully updated.' }
  else
    @position_count = ServiceMenu.count
    format.html { render :edit }
    end
end
```

**service_controller**

```
def new
  @service = current_tech.services.build
end



def create
  @service = current_tech.services.build(service_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @service.save
      format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

---

**schema**

```
create_table "service_menus", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                      limit: 255
    t.datetime "service_icon_updated_at"
    t.integer  "service_icon_file_size",    limit: 4
    t.string   "service_icon_content_type", limit: 255
    t.string   "service_icon_file_name",    limit: 255
    t.integer  "position",                  limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
  end


  create_table "services", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       limit: 255
    t.integer  "tech_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end


  create_table "techs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "username",               limit: 255
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size",       limit: 4
    t.string   "avatar_content_type",    limit: 255
    t.string   "avatar_file_name",       limit: 255
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,   default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                      null: false
    t.string   "first_name",             limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",              limit: 255
 end
```

---

**Question**

How can I perform the task of updating multiple records **dynamically** in the `services` db to the updated name in the `ServiceMenu` anytime I make a value change?
In order words:

- Update a record on `ServiceMenu` from the typo *Brakse* to *Brakes*
- After updating a record on `ServiceMenu`, Rails would find in the `services` db all the values in the `name` column that = *Brakse*
- Update all the *Brakse* values in the `name` column to *Brakes*

---

> Edit

Do something like this any time I update anything on `ServiceMenu` drop down menu.

```
if @service_menu.update(service_menu_params)
@service.update.where(name: "Old `ServiceMenu` value which , ie.**Brakse**", "The new `ServiceMenu` value which is now **Brakes**")
```

Please help on how to accomplish this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing some nuance to the question, renaming the Service item from Brakse to Brake is all you need to do -- the associations will remain the valid.

This assumes, of course, that the `services` table has a `name` field, but it's hard to know without seeing your schema.

If that's not the right answer, please show the entire schema, not just the associations.

Comment: I've added the schema contents pertaining to this post. A migration would be more of a manual process. I am looking for a more dynamic solution. I've also included more details.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you'd accomplish that by creating model relationships between entities. In your case, specifically, that would look something like this:

```
class Tech < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, inverse_of: :tech
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tech, inverse_of: :services
  belongs_to :service_menu, inverse_of :services
end

class ServiceMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, inverse_of: :service_menu
end
```

Now, if the `Service` model has a name column in the database (which it should, in this case), anytime that attribute is updated in the database, it will also be updated for each user, because they all have a relationship with that same database table.

In short, if you add the appropriate relationships to your models (as listed above), you aren't going to have to worry about anything of the sort. That's the beauty of Object-Oriented Programming.

Please note: the way your current model structure is set up, you're going to need foreign key references on your `Service` class, for both the `Tech` class, as well as the `ServiceMenu` class. That migration would look something like this:

```
rails generate migration AddTechAndServiceMenuRefToServices tech:references service_menu:references
```

That migration will add both `tech_id` and `service_menu_id` columns to your `Service` class, thus creating a proper relationship among your different models.

Comment: Hi Collin, I greatly appreciate your response. I've added all that you've mentioned except for the migration.
Since I already have a `tech` foreign key from a previous migration, I performed the following instead: add_service_menu_ref_to_services which created `add_reference :services, :service_menu, index: true` and `add_foreign_key :services, :service_menus, after: :name`. I've restarted the server and performed your instructions multiple x's but unfortunately was unable to achieve the desired results.

Comment: I think what I may be running into is that I am using `@service = **current_tech**.services.build`. Since I'm creating a new service as the `current_tech` (Devise helper), only the `tech_id` will be applied to the `services` db but not the `service_id`. It appears that I may 
Again, I do appreciate your help.

The closes I've gotten to achieving desired results is using this:
`Service.where(name: @temp_var).update_all(name: @service_menu.name)`
The _where clause_ does not recognize vars but rather actual "stings"

Answer (score 0):

These model names ServiceMenu and Service are really confusing in this context and should probably be Service and RenderedService respectively.  Having said that, let's see what you need to get this to work *without* needing that update statement at all.

Add the following relationships into the mix:

```
class ServiceMenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_menu
  belongs_to :tech
end

class Tech < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end
```

The Service model now refers to a ServiceMenu using its name which is where your confusion is coming in.  Instead of the name, have the Service model refer to the ServiceMenu using a service_menu_id by creating a migration like so:

```
rails generate migration AddServiceMenuIdToServices service_menu_id:references
```

Once these changes are made you'll need to adjust your code to use the new service_menu_id column in the Service model.

If previously you were doing something like:

```
s = Service.new(name: 'Brakes', tech: Tech.find_by(name: 'Bob'))
```

you should now do something like:

```
s = Service.new(service_menu: ServiceMenu.find_by(name: 'Brakes'), tech: Tech.find_by(name: 'Bob'))
```

Saving s will now save a reference to the specific ServiceMenu item that is currently called 'Brakes'.  If you change the name of this specific ServiceMenu item in the future to "Barkes" that change will be reflected in the Service model automatically because it's no longer storing the name of the service menu item in the service record.

If you were previously using something like:

```
s = Service.find(100)
puts s.name
```

to retrieve the name of the service menu item that the service was referring to, now you'd use something like:

```
s = Service.find(100)
puts s.service_menu.name
```

You'll still have a name field in the Service model that needs to be removed using a migration.  If you have existing data in this system, you'll need to populate the service_menu_id field for all Service models using the data in the name field.

Comment: Hi Javeed, thanks for your response. The `ServiceMenu` is a page which contains a single menu of vehicle items such as, brakes, shocks, muffler, etc.... The `ServiceMenu` is a restricted page accessible to admins only. I'd prefer `Techs` or anyone else not to add and remove menu items from this menu. What you've mentioned I've already had in place except for the `service_menu_id` migration. However, I was unsucessful at achieveing the desired results. As mentioned below in Collin's post, The closes I've gotten to achieving desired results is using this in the `service_menu` update action:

Comment: `Service.where(name: @temp_var).update_all(name: @service_menu.name)`
The `temp_var` is in the `edit` action. However, the _where clause_ does not recognize vars but rather actual "stings"